# APC doesnt save properties in fosuserbundle extended class

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine, fosuserbundle, apc

I have a problem with joining my Article entity with User (which extends FosUserBundle class). It works nice when i query database for it, but when i use APC:

`$driver = \Doctrine\Common\Cache\ApcCache();
$driver->save($key, $queryResult)`, and then ask for `php$driver->fetch($key)`
I receive data only for core FosUserBundle columns (id, email etc), but NULLS for my extra columns.

I have:

`mappings:
   FOSUserBundle: ~`

in my orm default entity manager configuration. Any idea what might happen?

Comment: Could you try and replace `mappings: FOSUserBundle: ~` with this: `auto_mapping: true`?

Comment: @IlyaYarkovets Even Auto_mapping is not enabled with multiple entity managers. I have two of them and removed one but this didn't help

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the fact that

a) FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface extends \Serializable

and

b) FOS\UserBundle\Model\User implements it.

What you need to do is override

```
public function serialize()
```

and

```
public function unserialize($serialized)
```

with implemtations that take your additional fields into consideration.

```
/**
 * Serializes the user.
 *
 * The serialized data have to contain the fields used by the equals method and the username.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function serialize()
{
    return serialize(array(
        $this->password,
        $this->salt,
        $this->usernameCanonical,
        $this->username,
        $this->expired,
        $this->locked,
        $this->credentialsExpired,
        $this->enabled,
        $this->id,
        $this->someCustomField,
    ));
}


/**
 * Unserializes the user.
 *
 * @param string $serialized
 */
public function unserialize($serialized)
{
    $data = unserialize($serialized);
    // add a few extra elements in the array to ensure that we have enough keys when unserializing
    // older data which does not include all properties.
    $data = array_merge($data, array_fill(0, 2, null));

    list(
        $this->password,
        $this->salt,
        $this->usernameCanonical,
        $this->username,
        $this->expired,
        $this->locked,
        $this->credentialsExpired,
        $this->enabled,
        $this->id,
        $this->someCustomField
    ) = $data;
}
```